# Администрирование

Tags: windows, linux

В организации от 70 компов. Какие трудности могут возникнуть в администрировании? Есть ли советы бывалых?

Comment: Каких компов, на чем, какие у вас знания? Какие функции, сколько человек? Конкретней бы.

Comment: 70 компов. от виндоса до линекса. нас 2 чел. Функции очень много - он обычной настройки до прокладки сети

Answer (score 3):

В организации от 70 компов.Могут возникнуть следующие трудности:

- Нехватка инструментов (отвертки, обжимные клещи, lan-тестер, ножи канцелярские, скотч и т.д.)
- Проблема прокладки сети (необходимо провести на большой высоте, необходимо провести через огромную стену, невозможно закрепить розетки, плохо обжатый кабель, обжатый не по стандарту кабель, ЭМ наводки на кабель и др.)
- Неисправное оборудование
- Отсутствие документации по проведенным работам и структуре ЛВС
- Отсутствие сервера БД учетных записей (Active Directory, Open LDAP, другие)
- Дыры в безопасности (не проведение процедур обновления ПО, слабые пароли, использование учетной записи administrator/администратор, отсутствие правил доступа для общего ресурса, отсутствие антивируса, отсутствие HIPS и др.)
- Отсутствие опыта работы с Windows/Linux
- Отсутствие систем повышения надежности (RAID, отключенная система восстановления, и др.)
- Возведение системы без плана
- Проблемы с подключением SMB клиентов
- Проблемы с настройкой сети
- Еще множество других возможных подводных камней

Есть ли советы бывалых?

- Планируйте
- Записывайте изменения
- Сохраняйте статьи по которым что либо настраиваете
- Храните дистрибутивы/драйверы на сетевом хранилище
- Имейте служебную флешку/внешний диск
- Имейте все необходимые инструменты (в т.ч. не думайте, что lan-тестер излишество)
- Имейте аптечку
- Имейте компьютер с доступом в интернет
- Используйте только лицензионное либо свободное ПО
- Задавайте вопросы на этом проекте

Надеюсь все достаточно расписал)

Answer (score 3):

Предыдущие посты вполне отвечают на вопрос, однако рискну добавить три копейки.

- Ещё раз повторю, документируйте свои действия и всё, что вы узнаете о своей сети. Форма документации не имеет большого значения, важно чтобы вы и/или любой другой человек, оказавшийся на вашем месте, могли в ней быстро найти нужную информацию. И ведите её всегда;
- При решении возникшей проблемы всегда предусматривайте откат в исходное (предыдущее) положение и не торопитесь;
- При решении возникшей проблемы всегда перебирайте варианты, начиная с самых простых, даже и тривиальных;
- По возможности, стандартизируйте программное обеспечение на хостах сети;
- По возможности, избавляйтесь от сервисов, привязанных к компьютерам пользователей (общие принтеры, папки и т. д.), ограничивайте права пользователей до необходимого и достаточного уровня. Однако без фанатизма! Если уровень безопасности, установленный вами, будет постоянно раздражать пользователя, рано или поздно он найдет способ его обойти. На мой взгляд, это хуже, нежели недостаточный её уровень, но соблюдаемый пользователем;
- Читайте документацию.

Answer (score 2):

Обычно в обязанности администратора парка рабочих станций входят:

- работа с учетными записями пользователей,
- обеспечение безопасности системы (антивирусы, права доступа...),
- резервирование данных (образы для заливки, репозитории данных...),
- обновление программного и аппаратного обеспечения (системные обновления, новая память...),
- а также починка и настройка в случае необходимости.

Соответственно, какие могут возникнуть трудности? Любые, связанные с выше перечисленными задачами, а именно:

- нехватка знаний и опыта (администрирование Linux, при опыте работы с Windows),
- невозможность спросить старшего товарища (его нет, он в отпуске, заболел и т.п.),
- нехватка фондов (надо что-то купить, а денег не дают),
- сбой системы в отсутствие администратора на работе (пошел спать, все сломалось),
- и т.п.

Answer (score 0):

Если всё сразу правильно настроено, то проблем почти не бывает. Иногда возникают при совместном доступе к файлу, например, когда один юзверь забыл его закрыть, а другой пытается переименовать папку, где этот файл лежит (это из моей личной практики). А файл - на серваке, в общем доступе. От кэша я сразу отказался, это они ещё больше там путались.

Answer (score -1):

Да в принципе трудностей никаких. Создай две учётные записи фдмин и юсер. На админ поставь пароль, который будешь только ты знать, а пользователи пусть через учётку юсеров работают, потому что есть такая проблема с ними - они очень любят удалять файлы, которые очень важны, могут удалить файлы системы `Windows` (а это уже считай винда будет выдавать ошибку, а переустанавливать не охота). Также поставь им антвирусы для флэшек, чтобы вирусы туда не загоняли. Я вот тоже на фирме работаю, тут 58 компов, всё сделал как я тебе написал и можно сказать целый день ничего не делаю, сижу в соц сетях.

Comment: Печалька на фирме...